# Shader multiply matrices

Tags: java, opengl-es, shader, vertex-shader

I have an issue I don't understand.

I have a shader

```
String[] vsSource = new String[] {
        "attribute vec3 aVertex;",
        "attribute vec3 aColor;",

        "uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;",
        "uniform mat4 uPMatrix;",

        "varying vec3 vColor;",

        "void main(void) {",
        "    vColor = aColor;",
        "    gl_Position = uMVMatrix * uPMatrix * vec4(aVertex, 1.0);",
        "}" };
```

I set both matrices `uMVMatrix` and `uPMatrix` and I want to multiply them in the shader. When I try that, my screen stay black.

When I multiply it in Java and pass it to one mat4 variable, I see my triangle.

```
String[] vsSource = new String[] {
        "attribute vec3 aVertex;",
        "attribute vec3 aColor;",
        "uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;",

        "varying vec3 vColor;",

        "void main(void) {",
        "    vColor = aColor;",
        "    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(aVertex, 1.0);",
        "}" };
```

Can someone tell me why I can't multiply them in the shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inverting the order of the matrices in the shader, i.e.

```
gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertex, 1.0);
```

Comment: did the trick... I thought that multiply is commutative!? Anyway thanks!

Comment: Matrix multiplication is (in general) _not_ commutative. Glad to hear it worked.